# Python: If Multiple Nones of Falses

Tags: python

While working with multiple conditions I am currently using following syntax:

```
if hasattr(myClass,methodA)==False or hasattr(myClass,methodB)==False or hasattr(myClass,methodC)==False: return
```

I wonder if there is a shorter way of doing the same. What I don't like particularly is that I have to use "==False" three times in repetition. Would it be correct if used this instead:

```
if not hasattr(myClass,methodA) or not hasattr(myClass,methodB) or not hasattr(myClass,methodC): return
```

Comment: Not only correct, but massively preferable. It's rarely good style to compare directly with `True` or `False`.

Comment: I'm curious. What is your use case that you have to check for the existence of so many different methods on your class?

Comment: There are multiple different class-instances submitted to the same function(method). Some class attributes and methods are common between all the classes. But some are unique to only one or few classes. Since I don't want to re-write the same function multiple times (a function for each class-instance) I put the verification code before trying to access a function or an attribute... Better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `if not all(hasattr(myClass,meth) for meth in ('methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC'))`

Comment: Should the single quotes be omitted from the methodA,B,C?  (I.e., 'methodA' is a string, whereas methodA without quotes is the method)

Comment: @RichS Nope, they should not. The `name` argument passed to `hasattr()` must be a string.

Comment: No, unless they're variables holding the method names as strings.  `hasattr` takes the attribute name as a string.

Comment: Not crucial, but wouldm a `tuple` not be faster than a `list` here?

Comment: @AlexThornton: I suppose it would.  That's a pretty hairsplitting optimization though.

Comment: It should be `any` instead of `all`, because he's using `or` in his example.

Comment: @LucianU: He's checking if any are False, which means not all are True.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally:

`if any(map(lambda method: not hasattr(myClass, method), ['methodA', 'methodB', 'methodC'])):`

Comment: No reason to use `map` and `lambda` instead of a list/generator comprehension.

Comment: Depends on your programming preference.  Those coming from functional backgrounds might prefer this way.  `map/lambda` is not necessarily something to be avoided.

Comment: map/lambda is almost always unpythonic compared to list/generator comprehension.  Here it also adds an additional function call which has a performance penalty (not significant here, but can be on a large list).  Those coming from functional backgrounds would do well to learn the Python way! ;-)